# Auto reloading on save of template file in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I know Quarkus has auto reload for resources and java files however, while editing a html template using the Qute templating engine you have to manually hit refresh in the browser. This can be a little tedious when making tons of small css changes.

Is there a way to have it when you save the resource it auto calls a refresh to your browser? Tried the LiveReload extension for chrome but I believe that is for local files instead of served files.

Comment: I imagine you could just use a browser extension that triggers page refreshes periodically, every few seconds? Like Easy Auto Refresh for Chrome, it can reload every second if you want to.
LiveReload is only for specific LiveReload-compatible web frameworks, I think Quarkus is not supported by it.

Comment: Yeah seems like the only solution at the moment until LiveReload is implemented, I created a request for it here which seemed to be a duplicate. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11761